# Why are all my shape objects null when I try to get perimeter?

Tags: java

Right now I am doing the classic shape program involving shape classes.  I can do the create circle or rectangle object  without any problem. But when I get perimeter or area of all the objects, it turns out all the objects are null. Here is the code:

//Case menu selection actions

Here it the instance variables and arrays

```
private int menu_select;
private int i=0;
private Shape[] s = new Shape[10];
```

Here is the menu options

```
public static void display_menu()
{
    System.out.print("Choose an option:\n"+
            "1-Add a new circle\n"+
            "2-Add a new rectangle\n"+
            "3-Delete all shapes\n"+
            "4-Scale all shapes\n"+
            "5-Display perimeter of all shapes\n"+
            "6-Display the area of all shapes\n"+
            "7-Enter scale factor\n"+
            "8-Exit program\n");
}
```

Here is the the menu code

Here is the switch

```
//Case menu selection actions
    public void select_case()
    {

        if(i<=10)
        {
            switch (menu_select)
            {


                 case 1: Circle c = new Circle(1);
                         s[i]=c;
                         i++;
                         break;
                 case 2: Rectangle r = new Rectangle(1,1);
                         s[i]=r;
                         i++;
                         break;

                 case 3: s=null;
                         i=0;
                         break;
                 case 4: Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  
                         double d = input.nextDouble();
                         for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
                         {
                             s[i].setScaleFactor(d);
                         }
                         break;
                 case 5: for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
                         {
                            if(s[i] != null)
                            {   
                                System.out.println(s[i].getPerimeter());
                            }
                         }
                         break;
                 case 6: for(int i=0; i<s.length; i++)
                         {
                            System.out.println(s[i].getArea());
                         }
                         break;
                 case 7: //Enter scale factor

                        //No need for a case 8 since while loop terminates it.
                 default: System.out.println("Number must be 1-8");

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the main method

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Menu m;
        do
        {
            Menu.display_menu();
            m = new Menu(0);

        }
        while(m.getMenu_Select() != 8);



    }

}
```

I have tried giving the shape array indice a fixed number and I still get a null object. I have also tried removing the for loop with the fixed indice and still get null objects.

Comment: It may be me, but I don't see enough information to be able to guess what you may be doing wrong. You may wish to show more code.

Comment: Please don't cut up the code like this. We need to see the whole `switch` statement.

Comment: Will you post a complete program with a `main()` method? Feel free to leave out the `case`s which don't apply to your current question. I will be glad to compile and run it on my end to test it out for you if you do this.

Comment: I'll start fixing the problem. I was only doing that just to prevent you from being overwhelmed

Comment: But with the risk of underwhelming us I'm afraid. We're terrible at guessing at code we can't see.

Comment: Why are you using the letter i everywhere? At least in the loops you can use j, k, l, something else.

Comment: The i is to count all the objects so there won't be more then 10 created. By the way I finished the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new Menu object with each iteration of the loop!

```
    {
        Menu.display_menu();
        m = new Menu(0); // here!

    }
```

Don't do that since any changes done on this object will have no effect or memory on the next object.

Create one Menu object *before* the loop, and then call methods on it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Does "i" can equal to 10 in the following code?

The maximum index in array s should be 9

```
public void select_case()
{
    if(i<=10)
    {
        switch (menu_select)
        {
```